# Why am I not able to import the city values which are defined in Cities.razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blazor, client

```
@page "/city"
@page "/city/{CityId}"
@inject ICityService CityService

@if (CityId == null)
{
    <PageTitle>Add a new City</PageTitle>
    <h3>Add a new City</h3>
}
else
{
    <Pagetitle>Edit @city.CityName</Pagetitle>
    <h3>Edit @city.CityName</h3>
}

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public int? CityId { get; set; }

    City city = new City { Country = new Country() };
}
```

```
@page "/cities"
@inject ICityService CityService
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Citie overview</PageTitle>

<h3>City Overview</h3>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> City Id</th>
            <th> City Name</th>
            <th> City Abbrevation</th>
            <th> Country</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var city in CityService.Cities)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@city.CityId</td>
                <td>@city.CityName</td>
                <td>@city.CityAbbrevation</td>
                <td>@city.Country.CountryName</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => ShowCity(city.CityId))"><i class="oi oi-pencil"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="AddNewCity">Create New City</button>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await CityService.GetCities();
    }
    void ShowCity(int CityId)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"city/{CityId}");
    }

    void AddNewCity()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/city");
    }
}
```

In the first page I am trying to use the same variables as in second page.

```
                 <td>@city.CityId</td>
                <td>@city.CityName</td>
                <td>@city.CityAbbrevation</td>
                <td>@city.Country.CountryName</td>
```

But I am not able to import the variables to the below page and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
@page "/city"
@page "/city/{CityId}"
@inject ICityService CityService

@if (CityId == null)
{
    <PageTitle>Add a new City</PageTitle>
    <h3>Add a new City</h3>
}
else
{
    <Pagetitle>Edit @city.CityName</Pagetitle>
    <h3>Edit @city.CityName</h3>
}

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public int? CityId { get; set; }

    City city = new City { Country = new Country() };
}
```

I am following a tutorial on youtube by Patrick god: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_P-qJj_8Bg&t=4211s&ab_channel=PatrickGod (min 40-44).

I've generated a model, controllers and services. The API works, but once I try to make an create and edit page it doesn't work.

Please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the CityService on the second page because you are only receiving the CityId and not all the related city data, like this:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    city = await CityService.GetCity(CityId);
}
```